# Ruby/Rails - Parsing and Displaying HTML from a Models Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, styling

I have a Rails Model called Events which has as field/attribute called :description.

I migrated it under the type `t.text` rather than `t.string` since I was going to be displaying a large amount of data.

So.... Now I'm at the point where I would like to display `<%= @event.description %>` in a neat way and would like to break up some of the sentences rather than one large block of information.

I was hoping I could insert `<p>` or other html codes to help with how the text is displayed.

The problem is inserting `<p>` into the field only prints `<p>` and the not desired action of the html command.

How can I add html styling to the text attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `<%=raw @event.description %>` to echo unescaped content. Be aware that this is a potential XSS security hole, if users can ever affect that content. I highly recommend using the [sanitize helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) to strip out any unwelcome markup before you write it out.

Answer (score 0):

It strictly depends on how you print it. In particular, if you print with calling `h` function (`<%= h my_text =>`), output will be sanitized and html escaped.

It may also depend on your rails version: I've head in Rails 3 html is escaped by default, even if you don't use `h`.